# What does absolute value sign mean when it's around the covariance matrix?

Tags: matrices, covariance

I have the following covariance formula and the probability formula:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to write these formulas in python, however, I couldn't understand that |$\sum|^\frac{1}{2}$

What does that operation mean?
I thought that I should get the absolute value of every element in the matrix and take the square root of them. Is this correct?

Comment: No, that would not be correct (notice how you're still somehow dividing by a matrix?). Most likely it represents some sort of matrix norm.

Comment: It is the determinant of $\Sigma$.